# Is a Pact Weapon a spell attack or a normal weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, warlock, attack

Basically, do I use Charisma to attack?

If not, is it a normal weapon? So if I create a Greatsword, I use Strength, but with a Scimitar I use Dexterity?

Do I apply feats, if I have Extra Attack from a Fighter multiclass, do I attack twice?

Comment: Note that at level 12 you can also add your charisma mod.

Comment: Note that if your Patron is the Hexblade, you can use your Charisma mod for attack and damage with your Pact Wepaon and with your Hexblade weapon.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You make a regular weapon attack with the weapon**

Nowhere in the *Pact of the Blade* section of the Warlock class does it describe or specify the pact weapon as making attacks using your spellcasting feature. You would use the appropriate stat (STR or DEX) that the weapon calls for. The advantage of making the Pact Weapon would be that you would have proficiency with that weapon if you didn't already and the fact that it counts as a magical weapon for the purposes of monsters resisting damage.

**Yes, the magic aspect of using a pact weapon is summoning or sending it away, not the attack**

Using a Pact Weapon is not like casting Shillelagh. If it were it would share the same language. For all intents and purposes of taking the Attack action a Pact Weapon is functionally identical to a normal weapon. Your extra attack would trigger from an attack made with it.

Answer (score 7):

**Basically, do I use Charisma to attack?**

No you don't use Charisma to attack it just creates a weapon that the Warlock can use and be proficient in. The weapon is used normally as part of a melee attack.

**If not, is it a normal weapon?** 
It is a normal weapons other than for the effects listed on page 107-108.

This is because of the rule that specifics beat general. There are no specifics that specifies a different attribute to be used for melee attack or that the weapon as any other characteristic than those listed.